# Chart Skinning Using p:layout and Dashboards

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I can't seem to get my code to work the way I want.  I'm attempting to format charts on a page with JSF templates.  I'm using JSF2.0, NetBeans 6.9.1, GlassFish 3.0.1 with Mojarra 2.0.3, and PrimeFaces 2.2. For the template I am using . I have placed the charts into dashboard panels. The charts themselves show up, but I cannot modify their size, or display the piechart legends. I have put the the style and script tags, shown in the documentation and showcase, on the main template page where the other css references are located. I've used this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .chartClass {
            width: 250px;
            height: 145px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var piechartStyle = {
            padding:20,
            legend: {
                display: "right",
                spacing:10
            }
        };
    </script>
```

On the template client page, where I display the charts, this is the code I've used:

```
    <ui:define name="main_base_content">
                <h:form>
                    <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardBean.model}">

                        <p:panel id="receipts_chart" header="Receipts Chart" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="200">
                            <p:pieChart model="#{receiptsChartBean.model}" styleClass="piechartStyle" />
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="shipments_chart" header="Shipments Chart" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="200">
                            <p:pieChart model="#{shipmentsChartBean.model}" styleClass="piechartStyle" />
                        </p:panel>

                        <p:panel id="receipts_graph" header="Receipts Graph" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="200">
                            <p:lineChart model="#{receiptsChartBean.lineModel}" var="line" titleX="Date" titleY="Number of Receipts">
                                <p:chartSeries label="Receipts" value="#{line.receipts}" />
                            </p:lineChart>
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="shipments_graph" header="Shipments Graph" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="200">
                            <p:lineChart model="#{shipmentsChartBean.lineModel}" var="line" titleX="Date" titleY="Number of Shipments">
                                <p:chartSeries label="Receipts" value="#{line.receipts}" />
                            </p:lineChart>
                        </p:panel>


                        <p:panel id="volume_received_graph" header="Volume Received - Graph" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="200">
                            <p:stackedColumnChart model="#{shipmentsChartBean.stackModel}" var="stack" titleX="Date" titleY="Receipts by Weight">
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer1" value="#{stack.stackedShipments}" />
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer2" value="#{stack.stackedShipments}" />
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer3" value="#{stack.stackedShipments}" />
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer4" value="#{stack.stackedShipments}" />
                            </p:stackedColumnChart>
                        </p:panel>
                        <p:panel id="weight_received_graph" header="Weight Received - Graph" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="200">
                            <p:stackedColumnChart model="#{receiptsChartBean.stackModel}" var="stack" titleX="Date" titleY="Receipts by Weight">
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer1" value="#{stack.stackedReceipts}" />
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer2" value="#{stack.stackedReceipts2}" />
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer3" value="#{stack.stackedReceipts3}" />
                                <p:chartSeries label="Customer4" value="#{stack.stackedReceipts4}" />
                            </p:stackedColumnChart>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:dashboard>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
```

The charts are filled with dummy data. They display, but the skinning is not working. I looked at the page with Firebug and see that despite setting the width and height of charts to 250px and 145px respectively, they remain at the default values.

[image: screenshot of Firebug]

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Do charts not work in layouts and/or dashboards? Oh, I've also tried putting the .chartClass into the cssLayout.css document - that did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to re-size the charts, and it has nothing to do with

```
<style type="text/css">
    .chartClass {
        width: 250px;
        height: 145px;
    }
</style>
```

I just used the "height" and "width" attributes of the different chart tags.  NOTE: for the pie chart tags, only the width seems to work. If I add in the height attribute the chart won't show.  That's okay though, because the width attribute seems to re-size the whole chart proportionately (which makes sense if you think about it - its a circle).  For the other chart types I used both the height an width tags.

I would still like to use the code shown above to resize all charts at the same time, but I'll work with what I've got.